# Task Manager appears on the screen by Windows 10 startup

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Is it possible to run TASK Manager using the startup functions of Windows 10 so that it automatically appears on the screen when Windows starts?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to the following executable:

```
%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe
```

Copy that shortcut to the following location:

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```